# System.typeloadException while running VS code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a beginner in software development. I was following a simple tutorial and was creating a web application in Asp.net MVC - 5. But suddenly my app stopped running even I did not do any fancy stuff. Below is the error I am getting. Please help me here.

Error: System.typeloadexception.
Additional: Microsoft,Ajax.Utilities.OutputVisitor from assembly 'WebGrease'

I have not touched these fancy stuff at all. But as soon as I run the application in local host I start getting this error. Error comes in _Layout.cshtml file near the line

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your targeted .Net framework version not installed on your System. Check your project properties .Net version and check your Pc has respective .Net installed.

```
try
  {

  }
  catch (TypeLoadException)
  { 
   // this can happen if respective .Net is not installed in your system
  }
```

> TypeLoadException is thrown when the common language runtime cannot
>   find the assembly, the type within the assembly, or cannot load the
>   type.

or add this code snippet

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AsemblyResolve += (s, e) =>
{
return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
  .SingleOrDefault(asm => asm.FullName == e.Name);
}
```

If all attempts fails, try to reinstall WebGrease nugget package